# How safe Skype is on rooted Android OS?

Tags: skype

Recently I have rooted my Android phone to third party custom ROM. After rooting, I have gone through many articles which says rooting cause serious security issues.

Now my question is: how safe is my Skype? Can anyone access my Skype account? Can anyone record the video conversation of mine? The provider of custom ROM has any hold or control over my phone?

Answer (score 1):

The provider of all the rooting software you use (such as Kingroot if you use a "one-click" technique, SuperSU, and any software you give root permission on your phone), and the provider of the ROM you use (whether it's a custom ROM or the stock ROM) has **complete control** over your phone. They can steal any passwords you type into the phone (in apps, websites, or your Google account details). They can take control of **any** app, including Skype. They can record all your conversations, steal your credit card number, and use your details to masquerade as you. They can lock your phone (as well as any online accounts you logged into) and demand a payment from you to get your files and accounts back.

When you decide to root your phone, you need to have complete trust in all the software you use to do it, which means you also need to trust the person you got it from (e.g. the website you downloaded it from). When an app on your phone asks for root permissions, you need to have complete trust in the source of the app. If you **don't** have complete trust, **don't** root your phone/install the custom ROM/install the app.

Comment: Well, that's depressing. True though. You could mention how, I don't know, SuperSU makes you see all root requests, or how ChainFire would lose his mind if someone thought his work was dangerous to their device?

Comment: @DanBrown Why would I need to mention that when you've just provided me with a good example of the kind of trust you need to have?

Comment: Because it's the kind of trust that is voluntary. If you don't trust an app, you can halt it's root auth. (Like the older versions of lucky patcher, which had a habit of wiping your entire davlik) Other apps that you can trust, Like tasker, you give root auth to. So one, big +1 to you (which I had already added) for noting how if you don't have the trust for root apps, don't bother with rooting. (Also, good spot in my wording!) Root auth apps can be trusted (except kingroot), but that's probably it.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you know that the apps you've got on your phone are safe and free from malware, your Skype should be safe as well. 
But remember: the Internet is not the greatest place for private data anyways.